# How to capture event when the ribbon is hided in SharePoint 2016?

Tags: sharepoint-server

We would like to do something when the ribbon menu is hided on the edit page.

So do we have any on change event about show/hide ribbon in SharePoint?
It would be best to have this event trigger in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Check below similar questions and posts I found:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462138/js-event-listener-for-when-element-becomes-visible

And

https://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-trigger-custom-event-show-hide-element/